# Is there any information if Deadpool will break the fourth wall in the 2016 film?

Tags: character, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool, fourth-wall

In the comic book, Deadpool is self-aware of his existence as a comic book character and often breaks the [fourth wall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth_wall).

[image: Deadpool referencing his existence as a comic book character | Deadpool breaking the Fourth wall]

Will they do this in the [upcoming film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadpool_%28film%29), too?

Is there any evidence or secured information, e.g. in the form of a recent interview or article about the film, that confirms or denies that this aspect of Deadpool will be part of the movie?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26896/discussion-between-panther-and-catija).

Comment: We significantly revised the question in an effort to reopen it. In its current form it does *not* seem to be about a rapidly changing event and does very well have a definitive answer. If that answer cannot be found until the actual release is a different question, but one that the "current events" close reason is *not* about.

Comment: It seems he already did it in X-Men Origins: Wolverine as per Deadpool Wikia

Later on, it was seen that even with his head cut off he was still alive and has his mouth back. He goes "Ssshhhhhh" to the audience (as some sort of a message that him being alive is to be kept a secret and is shown to have broken the fourth wall).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the green band trailer, Deadpool certainly seems to be self aware as a character in a film and does break the fourth wall. In one of the fight scenes he looks directly into camera and says "Cue the music." at around 1:28. This bit is omitted from the [red band trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4G4cjrHYAtE) (NSFW), which is what most people seem to be watching.

In addition to this, in an interview with [Empire](http://www.empireonline.com/features/deadpool-trailer-breakdown), there's a quote from the director about the Green Lantern reference in the preview where he specifically states that, while Wade Wilson doesn't break the fourth wall, he implies that Deadpool does.

> "That got a good laugh at Comic-Con. For the most part, we try to stick to the rule that Wade Wilson can’t break the fourth wall. He’s not aware that he’s in a movie. Deadpool is. He only breaks the fourth wall when he’s Deadpool. So we’re tiptoeing on the edge of breaking our own rule there, because he’s still Wade at that point.

This quote is from an interview at the 2015 Comic Con.

Comment: i searched a lot and got nothing, very nice answer.

Answer (score 2):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadpool_%28film%29#Development)

> Donner said that she wants the film to ignore the Deadpool of X-Men
>   Origins: Wolverine and reboot the character. She also stated that
>   Deadpool will have the attributes that the character has in the
>   comics, such as breaking the fourth wall.

Look [this link](http://www.empireonline.com/features/future-of-x-men-franchise/3.asp) too.

Comment: Is it not bit old news before reconsidering to make this film after leaked footage.

Comment: He did break the fourth wall in the teaser trailer for the trailer ("from the network that inexplicably sewed his mouth shut the first time..."), for what that's worth.

Comment: Not that I disagree that these words were said, but you might consider mentioning that they were said **5 years ago**.

Answer (score 1):

As an after the fact answer, having seen the movie, there is multiple instances of [Leaning on the Fourth Wall](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LeaningOnTheFourthWall), [Breaking the Fourth Wall](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BreakingTheFourthWall), and a complete [Lack of Fourth Wall](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NoFourthWall), as well as some [Lampshade Hanging](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LampshadeHanging) (A subtle difference from Leaning on the Fourth Wall).

As noted, in the trailers, the *"Please don't make my supersuit green or animated"* line is an example of Lampshade Hanging, as are the *"sewing his mouth shut"* moments. These are meta references that the audience knows about, but made some sense in-universe during the movie. The *"Cue the Music"* is also a Lampshade Hanging.

Once Wade has gone and adapted to being Deadpool, there are several Leaning on the Fourth Wall moments:

> Gum on the Car Window/Camera.
>  Glances towards the camera.

Then there is the direct Fourth Wall breaking:

> Deadpool directly speaking or referencing the audience multiple times. The other characters ignore this as typical Wade insanity. These asides are heard by the others but not understood/believed.

And a few moments of No Fourth Wall:

> The Breaking the Fourth Wall, while Breaking the Fourth Wall.
>  The Fast Forward, Rewinds, and movie flashbacks, as referenced by Deadpool.